# Why is my browser displaying a language that I have never choosen

Tags: windows, firefox

[image]

I am on Windows 10 64 bit and my Browser is Firefox version 60.0.1 64bit which is the latest.
The other language that is displayed is Tamil which i cannot read or write. This suddenly appeared this morning. After searching, I cleared the Cookies and site data and it went away, And came back again this evening. How can I prevent this from happening. I only want my Browser in ENGLISH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the search engine which was GOOGLE! Google was displaying the second language which had been switched on maybe by a site which used the language. Setting it to off did the trick!